# What is example of method overriding in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

As I went through tutorial, all written about get() method is example of method overriding.

But as per method overriding method which is present in parent class is having different implementation in child class.

And get() method is declared webdriver interface and implemented in RemoteWebDriver interface.

Then how overriding is achieved here?

Could you please help with query.
Any other example with method overriding in selenium webdriver please share?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking specifically for the `get()` function, here is the implementation tree:

```
public class ChromeDriver extends RemoteWebDriver
implements LocationContext, WebStorage, HasTouchScreen, NetworkConnection {...}
```

Here chromeDriver is an example class can be any other. It extends the `RemoteDriver` and implements a bunch of other interfaces. And the `RemoteDriver` Class extends and implements some more as below

```
public class RemoteWebDriver implements WebDriver, JavascriptExecutor,
FindsById, FindsByClassName, FindsByLinkText, FindsByName,
FindsByCssSelector, FindsByTagName, FindsByXPath,
HasInputDevices, HasCapabilities, Interactive, TakesScreenshot {
...
     public void get(String url) {
            execute(DriverCommand.GET, ImmutableMap.of("url", url));
...
}
```

As you can see the `RemoteDriver` is overrridng the `get()` method it gets from the `WebDriver` interface

```
public interface WebDriver extends SearchContext {
....
void get(String url);
....

}
```

Comment: But could see It was declared in WebDriver interface. Since it was Interface there was no implementation. Then how its overriding example.

Comment: It just an interface example

Comment: Overriding something we give different implementation in child class . And override method which was in parent.

Comment: It does not matter if you are inheriting from an interface or from a class, as long as you are changing a method that you inherit from parent, your are overidding it.

Comment: implementing methods of an interface in subclass is also known as Overriding. Overriding happens between Parent Class and Child Class. It also happens between Interface and implementing Subclass.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple overriding example of the "findElement" method.

```
    public static WebElement findElement(By Locator){

    WebElement anElement = fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            webDriver=sampleDriver;
            return sampleDriver.findElement(Locator);
        }
    });

    return anElement;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example. But it looks like the question is asking specifically about the `get()` method

Answer (score -1):

Overriding something we give different implementation in child class . And override  method which was in parent.